# when curl localhost:8080, 401 in centOS is it because of the jwt?

Tags: linux, spring, authentication, jwt, centos

My spring project works in IntelliJ with Chrome, but In linux it doesn't.
It is the result in my linux below.

```
>curl "http://localhost:8080"
{"message" : FAIL AUTHENTICATION, "status" 401}
```

I think it's because of jwt and spring security. So I change the setting "antMatchers("/**").permitAll()".
But It's not the solution.